# Spark cluster is not using all executors

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to optimize a long-running job in spark, it seems that no matter how many executors the cluster running with, the job still takes ~3 hours to finish.

checked Ganglia UI and I see there are executors that's are idle (!)

[image]
[image]

cluster setup:

1. yarn + spark with EMR cluster
2. 1 master + 4 workers
3. instance type: r5d.4xlarge 16 cores + 128GB memory + 2 x 300 NVMe SSD
4. PySpark + multi thread inside the script

What am I doing wrong?

spark configuration:

```
spark.executor.memory: 70G
spark.executor.cores: 70
spark.rdd.compress : false
spark.io.compression.codec : org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec
spark.io.compression.snappy.blockSize : 32768
spark.serializer : org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.kryo.referenceTracking : true
spark.kryo.registrationRequired : false
spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs : false
spark.memory.fraction: 0.7
spark.memory.storageFraction: 0.5
spark.scheduler.allocation.file: /home/hadoop/fairscheduler.xml
spark.scheduler.mode: FAIR
spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.blocking: false
spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval: 3min
spark.task.cpus: 2
spark.executor.instances: 4
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead: 45000
spark.default.parallelism: 64
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions: 64
spark.speculation: false
spark.speculation.multiplier: 5
spark.speculation.quantile: 0.80
spark.speculation.interval:  1000ms
```

Also, tried to repartition the data frame, it didn't help.

```
dataframe = load_raw_data(reader, id).repartition(64)
```

Comment: Can you share the jobs details from Spark UI ? You need to identify long jobs and stages to find a way to reduce their execution duration.

Comment: I can see it's spark count operation that takes most of the time. Its not explaining why I have idle exectors